# How to aggregate in 1 table

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions

I have an simplified example of my data:

| Soccer team | Player | Goals |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Man. City | Haaland | 3 |
| Man. City | De Bruyne | 0 |
| Man. City | Foden | 0 |
| Man. Utd | Hojlund | 0 |
| Man. Utd | Onana | 0 |
| Man. Utd | Maguire | 0 |

And now I want to add a column that checks if a team has any goalscorers.
So my result should be:

| Soccer team | Player | Goals | Goals in team |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Man. City | Haaland | 3 | y |
| Man. City | De Bruyne | 0 | y |
| Man. City | Foden | 0 | y |
| Man. Utd | Hojlund | 0 | n |
| Man. Utd | Onana | 0 | n |
| Man. Utd | Maguire | 0 | n |

How could I achieve this? Which SQL statement should i use.
Remember I have like 25 other columns. Should I still put it in an aggregation function and group by all of the other columns, or are there easier ways?

Comment: Use a window function over partition by team. Window functions keep the rows, group by groups by (mostly) into fewer rows.

Comment: That's not aggregation - the number of rows isn't reduced. Use a windowing function with `OVER` to calculate a value over a subset and repeat it in all rows, eg `IIF(MAX(Goals) OVER(PARTITION BY Team)>0, 'y','n')`. The expression `MAX(Goals) OVER(PARTITION BY Team)` calculates `MAX(Goals)` over all rows with the same Team value

Comment: Something like `Case when sum(goals) over (partition by soccerteam) > 1 then 'y' else 'n' end as GoalsInTeam` would be the column in your select

Comment: `I have like 25 other columns` what does that mean? The *actual* case matters. You may have to use UNPIVOT to get different column values as separate rows

Comment: While I don't expect scores to ever be negative, if they could be, you could get a sum of <0 while someone has a vlaue >0 so max may be a better option.  This just gets into edge cases and what do you mean by anyone having a goal on team.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `SUM()` with `CASE` statement.

```
SELECT SoccerTeam, Player, Goals,
    CASE WHEN SUM(Goals) OVER (PARTITION BY SoccerTeam) > 0 THEN 'y' ELSE 'n' END AS GoalsInTeam
FROM YourTable;
```

Comment: Thank you. It looks so easy, but I did not think of it myself. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a window function inside a CASE expression for this. I've put * in the query because you said you had lots of other columns. You should replace the star with the list of columns you want in the query. You can also put columns after the 'goals_in_team' column if you prefer.

```
SELECT  *, --replace with your list of columns in preferred order
        CASE 
            WHEN SUM(goals) OVER (PARTITION BY soccer_team) > 0 
            THEN 'y' 
            ELSE 'n' 
        END AS goals_in_team
FROM results;
```

Comment: Thank you. It looks so easy, but I did not think of it myself. :)